# React list, show active item onClick. Without re-rendering the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show different style for the stock item which is clicked, but when i set activeItem to idx clicked, react re-renders the whole list again. Is there any way to show only one active item without re-rendering the list

```
import React, { useState,memo} from "react";

const StocksList=({stocksData})=>{

    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(0);
    
    const Item=({stock,idx})=>{
        return (
            <li 
                className={activeItem===idx ? "active-stock-item" : "stock-item" }
                onClick={()=>{
                    setActiveItem(idx);
                }} 
            >
                {`${idx+1}. ${stock["Name"]}`}
            </li>
        )
    }
    
    return(
        stocksData.map((stock,idx) => <Item key={stock._id} {...{stock,idx}} />)
    )
}

export default memo(StocksList)
```

Comment: Normally, it should be good because you already added key on each item so that when there is update, react will not re-render the whole list but only those containing modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `key` on each rendered item.

```
stocksData.map((stock,idx) => <Item key={idx} {...{stock,idx}} />)
```

As a side-note, it's recommended not to use the index of the object as the key. If `stock` has an ID or some other unique identifier, use that.

#### Edit

Based on your comments, here's a working version that'll update select the active item:

```
import React, { useState,memo} from "react";

const stocksData = [
  {
    _id: 0,
    name: "Zero"
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "One"
  }
];

const Item=({ _id, name, active, onClick })=>{
  function onSelfClick() {
    onClick(_id);
  }

  return (
      <li 
          className={active ? "active-stock-item" : "stock-item" }
          onClick={onSelfClick} 
      >
          {`${ _id +1 }. ${name}. ${active}`}
      </li>
  )
}

export default function StocksList() {
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(stocksData[0]._id);

    function onClick(id) {
      setActiveItem(id)
    }
    
    return (
        stocksData.map(stock => <Item key={stock._id} active={activeItem === stock._id} onClick={onClick} {...stock} />)
    )
}
```

Comment: And maybe don't define the Item component itself inside the List render? I'd expect it to get recreated every time, key or not.

Comment: @rayhatfield when i put Item component outside, react wont re-render the list but highlighting each only one item wont work. It highlights each item I click, I want to highlight only one item.

Comment: @GAntoine, sorry my actual code had a key, I have updated the question.

Comment: @Navdeepkumar I've updated the answer with a working example.

Comment: Its a good solution @GAntoine